# Elasticsearch Geoshape query false results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I have two geo_shapes in ES. What I need to figure out is the best way to understand if one of the shapes (Green) contains or intersects with another (Red). 
Please see below a visual representation of three different cases:

Case I : is easy to detect - using Green shape coordinates make a Geoshape query with “relation" = “within”

Case II : also not a problem to do - using Green shape coordinates make a Geoshape query with “relation" = “INTERSECTS”

Case III : is a real problem - using Green shape coordinates I try to make a Geoshape query with “relation" = “INTERSECTS” and the Red shape is returned as the result…that is false - this shapes do not intersect with each other (I think so) even though one of the sides are touching each other….

Any way to avoid the false positive results here? Any other suggestions how to solve this task?

P.S. the coordinates are precise (example: 13.335594692338). There is no additional mappings like tree_levels or precision...

[image]

Comment: I do not understand why case 1 uses within, when the red/green polygons are next to each other (and touching on one side of the boundary).

Also, case 3, by definition, intersects.They are touching

Comment: Case 1 - sorry, I should make Red a little transperant...but it is within the Green rectangle (green rectangle is the same as in case2-3...)
Regarding intersection - agreed, but also disagreed - intersection is "crossing"...to be n the border of something doesn't mean crossing it;) Anyway, some solution will be great to define crossing and touching)))

Comment: unfortunately, ES does not support matching via 'touch'. It only provides intersect (which by definition means sharing one common point, regardless of whether it crosses. you might disagree with this, but this is the official definition.)

if you want a workaround, you can get the results back from elasticsearch, and use the JTS library, which does provide a touch method

Comment: Here is a reference to the JTS library I mentioned: http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jts/relate.html#intersects

Comment: @coffeeaddict Agree... Will have to try to play with ES first and probably will have to use external tools in case of bad luck))) Thank you for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every polygon which is stored in  Elasticsearch using geoshape is getting transformed into a list of strings. 
To narrow down this explanation a bit I'm gonna assume that the polygon you're storing in Elasticsearch is using geohash storage (which is default for geoshape type).

I don't want to get into great details but take a look at this image

[image: geohash]

and this description taken from Elasticsearch docs (the details don't match but you need to get the big picture):

> Geohashes divide the world into a grid of 32 cells—4 rows and 8
>   columns—each represented by a letter or number. The g cell covers half
>   of Greenland, all of Iceland, and most of Great Britian. Each cell can
>   be further divided into another 32 cells, which can be divided into
>   another 32 cells, and so on. The gc cell covers Ireland and England,
>   gcp covers most of London and part of Southern England, and gcpuuz94k
>   is the entrance to Buckingham Palace, accurate to about 5 meters.

You polygon is getting projected into list of rectangles, each being represented with a string (geohash). Precision of this projection is dependent on tree level. I don't know what's the default tree level for Elasticsearch but if you're finding false positives it seems it's too low for you.

A tree level of 8 [splits the world in rectangles of size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geohashes.html) `38.2m x 19.1m`. If the edge of your polygon goes trough the middle of this rectangle it may or may not (depending on implementation) assign geohash representation of this rectangle to your polygon.

To solve your problem you need to **increase the tree level** to match your needs (more on the mapping [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html)). Beware, though that size of the index will increase greatly (also dependent on size and complexity of shapes). As an example storing 1000 district size polygons (some having 100s of points) with a tree level of 8 - the index size is about 600-700MB.

Bear in mind that whatever tree level you choose you always risk to get some false positives as **geohash will never be 100% precise representation of your shape**. It's a precision vs performance trade-off and **geohash is the performance wise choice**.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation!!! Correct me if I'm wrong - basically I can try to play with "tree_levels" or  "precision" and set it to "1m" for example... (PS ES docs suggest to set '"tree": "quadtree", "precision": "1m" that sound reasonable in my case - maybe you can give some comment on that?)

Comment: Yes. You should experiment with those values. Bear in mind that you need to reindex your shapes each time you change the mappings.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! Will try to play with parameters and hopefully will be able to get more precise results))